# Troubles obtaining results from specific dates in Tweepy

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I have been coding a little program to obtain tweets from an especific period of time. This is what I have coded so far. The error I get when I run the code is File

```
"C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\tweepy\mixins.py", line 32, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError from None
AttributeError
```

And the code:

```
archivo= io.open("Boric2019.csv", "a", encoding="utf-8")

start_time = '2019-01-01T00:00:00Z'
end_time = '2020-08-01T00:00:00Z'

query = 'Boric -is:retweet'

for tweet in tweepy.Paginator(client.search_all_tweets, query=query, start_time=start_time,end_time=end_time, max_results=100).flatten(limit=1000):
    final=traductor.translate(tweet.full_text)
    textosinp= final.replace("´","").replace(".","").replace("\n", "")
    assembled="".join(textosinp)
    final2= assembled.rstrip()
    print (final2 )
    archivo.write(final2 +"\n")


archivo.close()
```

Comment: if you are using `api.search` then you are hitting the 7 day search API - dates outside of the past 7 days will not work. You need academic access and the v2 full search option (`client.search_all_tweets`) to use the data range you are trying to access. See https://dev.to/twitterdev/a-comprehensive-guide-for-using-the-twitter-api-v2-using-tweepy-in-python-15d9

Comment: Hello Andy, I do have academic access

Comment: In that case you should be able to use the API function I’ve indicated to get results for the range you’re looking at.

Comment: I'm using this piece of code and at the end, I added print(tweet.created_at). The results obtained are always from today. Is there something wrong in this piece?
start_time = '2019-01-01T00:00:00Z'
end_time = '2020-02-01T00:00:00Z'

for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search, start_time=start_time,
 end_time=end_time, q="Boric -filter:retweets", tweet_mode="extended").items(1000):

Comment: `api.search` is a totally different function to `client.search_all_tweets` which is what I specified. Please check the Tweepy documentation. `api.search` is only for the v1.1 API and only covers 7 days.

Comment: Hello Andy, I'd like to thank you for you answers. I think I got the point that you were telling me but there is still a problem i keep having. There is a limit of characters that I can post here, so I will update the post and maybe you can tell me where I am failing. I would be grateful, cause it migth be a little thing but I cant find it.